# InOrder sorting of a class within a AVLTtree by name to a text box

Tags: c#, avl-tree, inorder

I appear to have the tree displayed in order, however i want to display the country name in the text box instead of what it is currently giving me  Here is the code I have currently have relating to this issue. An FYI the tree populates from a file read in.

I want in the text box  Argentina, Australia, Brazil, etc. but current have "FormWork.Country, FormWork.Country, etc". Looking at them in the Autos shows they are the correct order, just not returning the Name only.

This is within Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
AVLTree<Country> countryTree = new AVLTree<Country>();
string buffer = null;

public form1()
{
LoadFile();
InitializeComponent();
orderTree();
}

public void orderTree()
{
countryTree.InOrder(ref buffer);
txtOrder.Text = buffer;
}
}
```

[This is where .InOrder is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yczxr.jpg)

My issues seems to be that I can't specifically retrieve "tree.Data.countryName" from the [Country.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D73XF.png) class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of calling

```
buffer += tree.Data.toString() + ",";
```

in the buffer append line of your in-order traversal, call something along the lines of

```
buffer += tree.Data.CountryName + ", ";
```

to access the string of the property you are trying to print rather than a representation of the Country object which will be "FormWork.Country".

Second off, you should put all of your code in the question rather than linking to 2 different places.

Comment: Additionally you can define the toString function of the Country class to return the CountryName and you will not have to change your inOrder implementation

Comment: I use a virtual desktop interface to access VS, and so cannot copy/paste code without rewriting it out, so i decided to screenshot it. I did try your method however and it didn't work, but I have recieved help elsewhere which fixed my issue using a ToString override.